# Show/Hide HTML5 element based on localStorage value

Tags: html, local-storage

In the below code, I have a button with id='questionaire'. When a user clicks on the button I want to save the event to the local storage so that the button would not be shown next time the user opens the page.

I managed to do this earlier with window.onload=function(){} script but then the button appeared for a moment and then disapeared, if it had been clicked. This didn't look nice.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Storage?</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        echo "
        <form>
            <input type='button' class='button' value='Question' id='questionaire'>
        </form>
        ";

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                document.getElementById('questionaire').onclick = function() {
                    localStorage.clicked = 'true';
                }
            </script>";
... <More HTML code> ...
    ?>      
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should always hide the button and show it when it was not clicked before.

when its hidden in the first place you won't get the flashing button for users who have already clicked it!

> This does not help. As this button is the topmost element in the page and if I don't show it at the first place and then show it after the page has loaded then all the other elements move. I have edited the question

wrap the button inside a div which has the dimensions of the button! then nothing moves

```
<div style="width: XXpx; height: XXpx; display: inline-block;">
    <input type='button' class='button' value='Question' id='questionaire'>
</div>
```

your problem is "the flash of unstyled content"
your page moves when showing or hiding the button on load with js, unless you hide everything until your manipulation is done!

you can try to google for "avoid flash of unstyled content" or read this: [Avoid Flash of unstyled content](http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/10/1-way-to-avoid-the-flash-of-unstyled-content)

Comment: You beat me to it. Dito this answer

Comment: This does not help. As this button is the topmost element in the page and if I don't show it at the first place and then show it after the page has loaded then all the other elements move. I have edited the question

Comment: (wrap the button inside a div which has the dimensions of the button! then nothing moves) - In this case there would be a hole in the page in case I don't show the button

Comment: @nikolai Anyways, if this is really the best solution, then I'll accept the answer

Comment: in asp.net and jsp there is a page lifecycle and you can manipulate the page prior to being rendered. i don't know if there is a way to do this in php